# Reset all data from calculator's screen

Tags: javascript, button, calculator, reset

I'm working with a .php and .html files trying to make a web calculator. Until now everything works ok apart from the reset button. On click I expected to see the screen clear from all data but it doesn't do this. The markup structured below:

```
<form id="myCalculator">
 <div id="screen"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="screenZero()" value="0">
  <input type="button" onclick="screenOne()" value="1">
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset">
</form>
```

...and the javascript:

```
function screenOne() {
 var one = 1;
 document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML += "1";
}

function screenZero() {
 var zero = 0;
 document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML += "0";
}

function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myCalculator").reset();
}
```

When the reset button clicked the screen still displays data rather than clear it. Any idea on how to make it properly work?

I notice that **document.getElementById().reset();** works perfectly with **html forms**, especially with **input** tag. However, it doesn't work with elements like **div or span** even if there are parts of html form.

Comment: Divs and spans are not form elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I change that to input but at the moment I get an error and try to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly. `reset` cannot work on a `div` element but this will:

```
document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "";
```

```js
function screenOne() {
 document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML += "1";
}

function screenZero() {
 document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML += "0";
}

function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="screenZero()" value="0">
<input type="button" onclick="screenOne()" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset">
```

I don't know why you're creating a function for every single `button`... that's not the way we should do programming.
Reuse your `function`!

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");

function insert(v) {
 screen.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", v);
}

function resetCalc() {
 screen.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
#screen{width:200px; height:2em; background:#eee; text-align: right;}
```

```html
<div id="screen">110</div>
<button onclick="insert(0)">0</button>
<button onclick="insert(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="resetCalc()">Reset</button>
```

Also, why using a `<div id="result">`? You could go with `input`:

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");

function insert(v) {
  screen.value = screen.value + v
}

function resetCalc() {
  screen.value = "";
}
```

```css
#screen{text-align:right;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="screen" value="" readonly>
<button onclick="insert(0)">0</button>
<button onclick="insert(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="resetCalc()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip!Actually, it is perfectly working. However, I'm trying to follow your suggestions especially those which recommend less typing and reuse, but when I click a button, no matter which one, I've been redirected to another page, even if I remove all the javascript code it does the same thing(!).

Comment: @JohnGreg (that's cause `<button>` submits the form by default) use `event.preventDefault();` inside the `insert` function **or** remove the `<form>` it's useless for a calculator (well... unless you have plans to submit your form :D ).

Comment: Yes! The event.preventDefault(); prevents the submission.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` element is not known as a valid input field for a form. If you want to clear the content of your div, you just need to pass an empty string to its innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = '';
```

However, I recommend to use an input field like this one:

```
<input type="number" id="screen" />
```

You can access its value with

```
document.getElementById('screen').value
```